# How to render a page after querying the db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question about the code below:

```
router.get('/friends', function(req, res) {
var friends=[];
var photos = [];

  if (req.session && req.session.user) { 

User.findOne({ email: req.session.user.email }, function (err, user) {
  if (!user) {

    req.session.reset();
    res.render('login',{message:'Session is timed-out. Login to your account'});
  } 
  else {      
    res.locals.user = user; // expose the user to the template 
   async.forEach (user.friends ,function (item,index, arr) {
      friends.push(item);
      var cursor = User.findOne({ email: item });
        photos.push(cursor.coverPhotoUrl); 
         console.log(cursor);  


    });//

       res.render('friends',{friends: friends, photos: photos});  
  }//else



   });
  } else {
    res.render('login',{message:''});
  }
});
```

What i'm trying to do is to iterate over the user's friends (the user holds his friends as an array of strings- his friends emails )
for each email adress i retrieve, i'm trying to look for the specific user in the db in order to get his 'coverPhotoUrl' field and insert it into an array.

After doing all that, i want to render a page and send it the two arrays i have created, but it is doing me some trouble because of the callback function in the 'findOne' query which is being called after the page has already been rendered, so the arrays i am sending are empty.

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code. I have tried to add callback to findOne() call for friend and add to friend . Moreover you can check whether current element is  last element and then render the page

```
router.get('/friends', function(req, res) {
var friends = [];
var photos = [];

if (req.session && req.session.user) {

    User.findOne({
        email: req.session.user.email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {

            req.session.reset();
            res.render('login', {
                message: 'Session is timed-out. Login to your account'
            });
        } else {
            res.locals.user = user; // expose the user to the template 
            async.forEach(user.friends, function(item, index, arr) {
                friends.push(item);
                // add callback to findOne Call
                User.findOne({
                    email: item
                }, function(err, cursor) {
                    if (cursor) {
                        photos.push(cursor.coverPhotoUrl);
                        console.log(cursor);
                    }


                });
                // ALSO CAN ADD LENGTH CHECK TO GET IF THE CURRENT ELEMENT IS LAST ELEMENT
                if (user.friends.indexOf(item) == user.friends.length - 1) {
                    res.render('friends', {
                        friends: friends,
                        photos: photos
                    });
                }

            }); //


        } //else
      });
  } else {
      res.render('login', {
          message: ''
      });
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The async.forEach function is asynchrnous, thus it is returning immediately, at which time your friends and photos array will be empty since they have not been filled out.

The 3rd parameter into forEach can be a callback, which will only complete after all iterations have been completed. You should put your res.render there. See https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: it still doesn't work... it stuck while trying to render the page